# Group by "outer reference" error in SQL server

Tags: sql-server, group-by

I am using a simple group by statement in the code below:

```
SELECT 'bcg-measles1'  AS vaccgroup,
        e0.providerid,
        ( SELECT count(DISTINCT e1.baseentityid) AS count
               FROM bcgmeasles1 e1
              WHERE e1.measles1_ = 'Vaccinated'  AND e0.providerid = e1.providerid) AS numerator,
        ( SELECT count(DISTINCT e2.baseentityid) AS count
               FROM bcgmeasles1 e2
              WHERE e2.measles1_ <> 'Not Eligible'  AND e0.providerid = e2.providerid) AS denominator
       FROM bcgmeasles1 e0
      GROUP BY 'bcg-measles1' , e0.providerid
```

I am facing an error which says:

```
Each GROUP BY expression must contain at least one column that is not an outer reference.
```

I do not understand why this error is showing up, as I am only doing a simple group by. Please help!

Comment: Just do `GROUP BY e0.providerid` you don't need to add the constant string to it

Comment: I am not sure (full repro would help), but please note that there are 3 "group by"s in the query - each of the select count(distinct) turns into a group by, and it is possible that the optimizer is seeing that the column is the same as an outer reference to one of those and throwing an error.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The error message is

> Each GROUP BY **expression** must contain at least one column that is not
> an outer reference.

You have

```
GROUP BY 'bcg-measles1' , e0.providerid
```

This contains **an expression** 'bcg-measles1' that is just a constant string literal.

Remove that to resolve the issue (as noted by @Charlieface).

But in any event a simpler way of producing these results would be to use the below

```
SELECT 'bcg-measles1'  AS vaccgroup,
       providerid,
       COUNT(DISTINCT CASE WHEN measles1_ = 'Vaccinated' THEN baseentityid END) AS numerator,
       COUNT(DISTINCT CASE WHEN measles1_ <> 'Not Eligible' THEN baseentityid END) AS denominator
FROM   bcgmeasles1
GROUP  BY providerid
```